# Aren’t my filters supposed to have a red dot when there are new questions?

Tags: bug, custom-filters

After not using this feature in a while, I noticed that none of my filters show [the red dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1SVK.png), despite all having new questions since I looked at each filter:

[image: Three filters, none lit up]

These are Stack Overflow filters, which should light up practically every single time I see them due to the amount of traffic. I noticed this problem on another site too though, where there would be only be one or two new questions matching the filter since I checked.

I found this feature helpful, so can it be fixed?

(Browser: iOS Safari. Let me know if anyone else sees this problem too.)

Comment: I came across this lots of times, most recently on Electrical Engineering SE (Chrome 83, Windows 10).