# Red dot near the question title

Tags: support, design, custom-filters

Just noticed a red dot near the new question and a tooltip for that:

> [image: new activity]

And near the custom filter name:

> [image: custom filter]

After clicking on the red dot near filter (it disappeared) and then I saw the list of questions (top 6 of them was with red dot):

> [image: list of questions]

Here's the animated gif:

> [image: red dot animation]

An easy way to reproduce is to create filter that would match any question, i.e. that contains `[tag:support] or [tag:bug] or [tag:feature-request] or [tag:discussion]`, [ask a new question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), then open site [home page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Is there any annonce post about such functionality?

Comment: I don't see this? Could it be a userscript attempting to highlight a new or active post?

Comment: @Catija I see it too, but in the Moderator Team: https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/questions The announcement is here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368523/4751173 but I'm not sure if it's supposed to be rolled out to Meta.SE.

Comment: probably an `#ifdef TEAMS` got misplaced ...

Comment: @Glorfindel yeah... it's a Teams feature but shouldn't be on public.

Comment: @Glorfindel me too

Comment: @Catija I've never use a userscripts for SE sites. One more hint is that I saw the same red dot near the custom filter on the right panel, but didn't take a screenshot that time. So it seems like a [bug] due to the comments, because this feature should be available only for Teams.

Comment: @rene a backdoor to the Teams... be the part of it!

Comment: It's just mostly odd because Teams is explicitly SO only. I'd understand if you saw this on SO but it's confusing that you're seeing it on MSE.

Comment: @Catija Added screenshot for custom filters. Here's on MSE again :)

Comment: On the filter I've seen it before, I even recall having asked a question about that on MSO

Comment: Could I hope for the discount for my team for the detected bug? :)

Comment: Well not my question, but related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389244/how-do-i-opt-out-of-red-dot-on-custom-filters-and-questions

Comment: I thought that custom filters are supposed to show the red dot if there were some new questions. And it seems that I am not the only one: [Aren’t my filters supposed to have a red dot when there are new questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345668)

Comment: @Martin that's for the dot near the filter itself, not near the questions. The expected behavior is to click on the filter, then you see the list of questions matching the filter.

Comment: It's sounding like the filter dot and the question dot are separate things, one being by design and one not. Is there anyone else who's seen the dot **on a question**?

Comment: @Catija I've added a way to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I can confirm that it works like that @αλεχολυτ

Comment: "create filter that would match any question" - that's not a filter, it's not what the filters are for. You're using a feature in a way it shouldn't be used, so it's natural to get unexpected behavior. Maybe it's a bug, but a bug caused by misusing a feature. Like the good old reproducing loading icon when you keep submitting a comment.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard I agree that such type of filter is not useful, but this is an easy way to reproduce the issue. The more questions satisfy the filter, the more frequently situation will shoot.

Comment: No, when you set a real filter there won't be a dot unless you actually go to the filter. At least that's how it works for me.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard I don't' understand your "No". There's an issue (bug) because according SO employee (Catija) these red dots should be only available for Teams (or at least wouldn't cross StackOverflow site boundaries).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ I think she meant that in Teams the red dot appear in the questions list always, when there is new custom filter activity. It's nice, but it's a Teams-only feature. The f2p version shouldn't show the red dot in questions list, and it's not, except when you make a special filter on all questions. The "No" is about "The more questions satisfy the filter, the more frequently situation will shoot" - since it happens only with specific "All Questions" filter, I can't see how it is relevant.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard you can always replace "All Questions" filter with more narrow  filter like "Bugs only" or something else. The main key of the reproductible steps is  creating the question that sitisfy your filter. No matter what are actual filter will filter.

Comment: I don't know when it was added but it doesn't sound like a bug, so I've removed the tag. You click on your filter (with a red dot) the red dots show which posts are new... that seems like a reasonable design choice. I don't see a bug here.

Comment: @Catija If I understand correctly [bug] was added by ShadowWizard after your [statement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356432/red-dot-near-the-question-title#comment1190957_356432) that this feature is for Teams (SO) only.

Comment: Heh. I meant that I don't know when the feature was added :D I have never used filters, so I've never seen the feature and your question wasn't originally tied to the usage of filters or viewing posts through a filter, which meant it wasn't a complete question. :D So I edited to remove the bug tag rather than closing as by-design, since the goal of your question seems to be hinged on when the feature was created, rather than whether it's a bug that needs fixing. :D